# Modeling angles and magnitudes using a bi-variate gaussian.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, descriptive-statistics, chi-squared, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I have a bunch of points in n-d space who's coordinates follow a Normal distribution $(X=x_1,x_2,...,x_n\sim N(0,1) )$.

The coordinates form an angle $\theta$ (with respect to some arbitrary vector $V$) and a magnitude, which I plot.

I calculate the angle of each point using

$$\theta = \cos^{-1}\left( \frac{X \cdot V}{\lvert X \rvert \lvert V \rvert} \right) $$

Then I plot (in 2D) the angles and magnitude for each point.

**I am trying to model this distribution in 2D**. This way I can sample 2 random variables ($a$ and $b$) and I can calculate the angle with $\tan^{-1}(a/b)$ and the magnitude with $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

At first I figured I would be able to use a **bi variate gaussian**, but since the magnitude follows a chi-distribution ($\chi_N$), I don't get exactly the same distribution. Since the chi PDF is very low towards zero (for $N > 1$), I get a **donut-like distribution in simulation**, and a **circular distribution with my model**.

**Is there a better distribution I could use to describe the magnitude?** (I'm guessing $a$ and $b$ would be bi-modal gaussians, but how do I go about doing that ?)

**PS**: I calculate the variances of the components the bivariate gaussians ($a,b$) like so:

\begin{align}
\text{var}[\lvert X\rvert^2] &= \text{var}[\chi^2_N] \\
&= \text{var}[a^2 + b^2] \\
&= \text{var}[N(0, \sigma)^2 + N(0, \sigma)^2  ]\\
&= \text{var}[\sigma^2 \ N(0,1)^2 + \sigma^2 \ N(0,1)^2 ]\\
&= \sigma^4 \ \text{var}[N(0,1)^2 + \ N(0,1)^2] \\
&= \sigma^4 \ \text{var}[\chi^2_2]\\
\sigma &= \left( \frac{\text{var}[\chi^2_2]}{\text{var}[\chi^2_N]} \right)^{1/4} \\
\Sigma &= \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2 & 0\\
0 & \sigma^2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: In the absence of any actual analysis, which there probably is somewhere, you might model $X\cdot Y / |X| |Y|$ with an appropriate beta distribution.